# mysql: update a query if not exist any row by where condition then insert a new data

Tags: mysql

I need to update a table by some condition, not with primary key.

I am trying to do something like following

> update p_price set price = :price where p_id = :pid and c_id = :cid 
>   if there is no any row with where p_id = :pid and c_id = :cid then insert into p_price (p_id, c_id, price) value (1,2,3)

is that possible with sql command?

note: there are no primary key so I can not use ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: You are aware that this does not need a _primary_ key, but a _unique_ key will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it doesn't need to have a primary key. It only needs atleast unique constraint. Add this `UNIQUE` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE p_price ADD CONSTRAINT tb_unique UNIQUE(p_id , c_id);
```

and execute this statement,

```
insert into p_price (p_id, c_id, price) 
value (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE price = :price
```

*just change the values that first your needs.*

Comment: Even better: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = VALUES(price)`

Comment: I thought JW was wrong, but he is right... shown here in sqlfiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48c8e/1